# Solving cauchy hyperbolic second order pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm currently taking a course in partial differential equations. I'm trying to solve the following problem (which is, as far as I can tell, a bit above the level of the course):

> $$\begin{align} u_{xy}&=u \\ \Omega &= \{ x \le y , -\infty \lt x \lt \infty \} \\
>   u(x,x) &=  \begin{cases} 0   & x<0 \\ x^2 & x \ge 0
>  \end{cases} \\ u_y(x,x) &= 0 \\ \end{align} $$
>
> (using subscript notation to denote partial derivatives)
>
> $u(x,y)$ is continuously differentiable in the solution domain
> ($\Omega$), and analytic outside some curves.

I tried solving by modifying some methods (e.g. [d'Alembert's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Alembert%27s_formula)) but it didn't work, I could also identify the equation as 1-dimensional [Klein–Gordon Equation](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde203.pdf) and found some particular solutions to the equation, but not to my problem.

How can I solve such a problem?

I prefer a general approach for solving similar problems, but a specific solution will be good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can gather from  my old Graduate PDE course, what you want to do is use something called a [**Riemann function**](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Riemann_method) for the PDE.  I refer to my text on the subject, Guenther & Lee, *Partial Differential Equations of Mathematical Physics and Integral Equations*, Prentice-Hall (1988), Sec. 4-6, pp. 114-121.

A Riemann function is akin to a Green's function for second-order ODE's and some PDE's.  It is a mapping $R:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}$, and is used as follows.

Consider the following integral:

$$\int_x^y dx' \, \int_{x'}^y dy' R(x,y,x',y') [u_{x'y'}(x',y')-u(x',y')] = 0$$

The integral is over a triangular region above the line $y'=x'$ and thus in the domain of the given PDE.  Through a bit of trickery, we may rewrite the above integral equation as follows.

$$\int_x^y dx' \, \int_{x'}^y dy' [(R u_{x'})_{y'} - (R_{y'} u)_{x'} + (R_{x'y'}-R) u] = 0$$

We may try to solve this integral equation in many ways, but one way is to define $R$ so as to eliminate unknown quantities.  For example, as we do not know $u$ in the integration region, we may require that

$$R_{x'y'}(x,y,x',y') - R(x,y,x',y')=0 \quad x \lt x',  y \lt y'$$

We may also carry out the other integrations and form other requirements on $R$.  I will summarize.  When the following conditions are met:

$$R_{x'}(x,y,x',y) = 0 \quad x \lt x'$$
$$R_{y'}(x,y,x,y') = 0 \quad y \gt y'$$
$$R(x,y,x,y)=1$$

Then

$$u(x,y) = R(x,y,y,y) h(y) - \int_x^y dx' \, R(x,y,x',x') \phi(x') - \int_x^y dy' R_{y'}(x,y,y',y') h(y') $$

where $h(y)=u(y,y)$, $\psi(y) = u_y(y,y)$, and $\phi(y) = h'(x)-\psi(x)$.  The equation defining $\phi$ is a result of a consistency condition:

$$h'(x) = \phi(x)+\psi(x)$$

Recall we are given $h(x) = x^2 \theta(x)$ and $\psi(x)=0$, $\theta$ being the Heaviside step function.  NB $h'(x) = 2 x \theta(x) + x^2 \delta(x)$.

I refer you to the cited text as to determining $R$ given the above conditions.  The result is

$$R(x,y,x',y') = J_0{\left ( 2 \sqrt{(x'-x)(y-y')} \right )} $$
$$R_{y'}(x,y,y',y')= -\frac{J_1{\left ( 2 \sqrt{(y'-x)(y-y')} \right )}}{\sqrt{(y'-x)(y-y')}} (x+y-2 y')$$

where $J_0$ and $J_1$ are the Bessel functions of the first kind, zeroth and first order respectively.  The solution is then

$$\begin{align}u(x,y)  &= x^2 \,\theta(x) + \int_x^y dy' \frac{J_1{\left ( 2 \sqrt{(y'-x)(y-y')} \right )}}{\sqrt{(y'-x)(y-y')}} (x+y-2 y') y'^2 \, \theta(y')\end{align}$$

**ADDENDUM**

Here's a plot of $u(x,x+k)$ for $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,9\}$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! If you can post the code you've used to plot the function it would be great! I'm trying to understand how the singularity (in the second derivative) will behave in the solution. I could Plot3D the function itself in Mathematica using NIntegrate, but couldn't plot the derivatives...

Comment: Here's the Mathematica code: 

sol[x_, y_] := 
 x^2 HeavisideTheta[x] + 
  NIntegrate[(BesselJ[1, 2 Sqrt[(y - u) (-x + u)]] (x + y - 2 u))/
    Sqrt[(y - u) (-x + u)] u^2 HeavisideTheta[u], {u, x, y}];

Plot[Table[sol[x, x + k], {k, 0, 9}], {x, -10, 12}]

I wouldn't use Plot3D because it would be hard to appreciate the behavior of the solution.  For a start, I like plotting the curves as I have.  You may want to rewrite the integral in terms of $u(x,x+k)$.  ContourPlot is another option.